# Как добавить ссылки в popupmenu

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

Иногда в одном `TextView` может быть несколько ссылок. Но так как экран маловат, бывает не попадаешь на нужную. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на `TextView` появлялось меню с со списком ссылок.

Например. Как на мобильных телефонах, когда приходит СМС с несколькими номерами телефонов, когда нажимаешь "позвонить" появляется список с номерами которые в СМС.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `PopupMenu`:

```
textView.setOnClickListener((View v)-> {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popupmenu);         
});
```

`R.menu.popupmenu` - обычный ресурс меню, впрочем его можно и программно генерить.

**Update**

```
textView.setOnClickListener((View v)-> {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        //popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popupmenu);         
       //Извлекаем из TextView ссылки:
        URLSpan spans[] = textView.getUrls();
       //пихаем их в menu
       for(URLSpan span:spans) {
          popupMenu.addItem(span.getURL());
       }
       popupMenu.show();
});
```

Comment: Да, но как извлечь и добавить туда URL-ссылки?

Comment: Что извлечь и куда добавить?

Comment: Из TextView извлечь ссылки, добавить их в массив а затем в PopupMenu.

Comment: см. апдейт - а вообще читайте документацию - там все изложено

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Очень помогло.

Comment: Может кому поможет: мне нужно было переписать "popupMenu.addItem(span.getURL());" на "popupMenu.getMenu().add(span.getURL());"